# Ring of polynomials become a field

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

The K vector space K[α] is of finite dimension.
Then The ring K[α] is field.
Where α is an algebraic element..
I want an explanation and an example, i thought x doesn't have an inverse thus K[x] can never be a field just a ring, how come its a field here???

Comment: This is $K[\alpha]$ for an algebraic element $\alpha$ which belongs to some extension field $F$ of $K$. This is not the same as $K[x]$.

Comment: Probably some confusion with the notation. $k[x]$ usually denotes the ring of polynomials with coefficients in a field $k$. $k[\alpha]$ is different. This is the field $k$ adjoined with the element $\alpha$.

Comment: If $c_n\alpha^n+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+c_2\alpha^2+c_1\alpha+c_0=0$ with $c_0\ne0$, then $\alpha^{-1}=-\dfrac{c_n}{c_0}\alpha^{n-1}-\dfrac{c_{n-1}}{c_0}\alpha^{n-2}-\cdots-\dfrac{c_2}{c_0}\alpha-\dfrac{c_1}{c_0}$

Comment: The typical scenario is that $x$ in $K[x] $ is an indeterminate and then this has infinite dimension over $K$. But here the finite dimension of $K[\alpha] $ changes everything.

Comment: Also you should try to prove that $K[\alpha] $ is a field (a typical approach is via gcd of polynomials and Euclidean algorithm) and if you face any issues let us know by updating your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example, maybe that will make things clearer.

Consider $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$. It is, in some sense, the polynomial ring over $\Bbb Q$ in the variable $\sqrt2$. A typical element looks like
$$
5\sqrt2^3-\frac75\sqrt2^2+2\sqrt2-\frac{140}{23}
$$
However, it is also the case that $\sqrt2^2=2$, which means that the above can be simplified to
$$
12\sqrt2-\frac{1022}{115}
$$
This simplification allows us to construct inverses to any non-zero element of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$. For instance, the above element has inverse
$$
\frac{13\,225}{2\,764\,316}\left(12\sqrt2+\frac{1022}{115}\right)
$$

Comment: Then what is Q(x)?? The field of fractions of it, how do you represent it they will be both equal.

Comment: Can you give me an example where Q(a) differs from Q[a]??

Comment: if $x$ is not algebraic, then $\mathbb Q[x]$ is polynomials and $\mathbb Q(x)$ is rational functions