# Polynomial Set Notation

Tags: polynomials, notation

How do you read out the notation in the screenshot below. I know that the polynomials *f(x)* and *g(x)* are in the range of the real numbers but what is the significance of the [*x*] after the range.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyeWT.png)

Comment: The ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb R$  is $\mathbb R[x]$, i.e., $\mathbb R$ with a transcendental element $x$ adjoined

Comment: The polynomials when evaluated have values in $\mathbb R$, but the polynomials themselves are elements of $\mathbb R[x]$

Answer (score 1):

I personally dislike this notation, but its pretty standard. Given a polynomial
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$$
If
$$a_0,...,a_n\in S$$
For some arbitrary set $S$ (usually a ring or field) then we write
$$f\in S[x]$$
There are two main reasons I think this notation is abhorrent:

- $S[x]$ looks like a functional that takes in some function $x:t\to x(t)$
- It seems to suggest the variable used when writing out the function must be $x$, when of course this should be completely arbitrary.

Why we can't use something better like $\text{Poly}(S)$ baffles me.

Comment: $\mathrm{Poly}(S)$ works okay for $S[x]$, but less well for things like $S[x][y]$ and very poorly when you need to write a particular polynomial for something like $S[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ (though notation varies) since you'd need to agree on a standard letter for the variable.

Comment: I was going to ask:   Poly($S$) works okay instead of $S[x]$ for a transcendental element adjoined to $S$, but how would you denote $S$ with an algebraic element adjoined (e.g., $K[\alpha]$ [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932266/ring-of-polynomials-become-a-field))?

Comment: Two comments: First, that $S[x]$ looks like a functional is probably due to the fact that you learned that use of the notation first. I, on the other hand, always read this as the polynomial ring and don’t quite understand why you would need special brackets for the application of a functional anyways (unless you routinely want to identify a function $f$ with its value $f(x)$). Second, it is important to keep in mind that to an algebraist, a polynomial is more than just a function: A polynomial always has a well-defined sequence of coefficients (whereas to different sequences of coefficients

Comment: can define the same function over finite fields, for example). Hence using the notation $x \mapsto a_0 x^n + \cdots + a_n$ for polynomials would be confusing as that notation is for functions. We still want to be able to write down a polynomial, though. To achieve this, we want a name for the polynomial with coefficient sequence $(0, 1, 0, 0, \dots)$. The notation $S[x]$ introduces the polynomial ring and a name for this special polynomial at the same time; using $x$ and elements from $S$ we can write down any polynomial we want. Of course, the name we choose has no real relevance but it is

Comment: nice to be able to pick several different names in cases where you have several polynomial rings or polynomial rings in several variables.